# How to draw a custom DataGridView multi-column header

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I've done this with and asp.net grid view and header templates and I need to port this same concept over to my winform application. I'm trying to find a way to have a cell or label  span the width of several sub-headers. There are third party controls that do this but buying one is not an option at this time.

Here is an example of the web version I made:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataGridView doesn't have built in support for column spanning.  You might be able to hack something together by deriving your own Cell and Column types.  The cust DataGridViewCell would be a single row datagrid.

To accomplish this kind of asp.net like templating you almost always have to drop down into some sort of owner-draw/custom drawing solution in WinForms.